# Hot to pass values throw a onSuccess response runnable?

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit, runnable

So my goal like the the title says is to pass `API` response results throw an `onSuccess.run()` method to a fragment. Just to give some context, I start to do the method like this in a Manager class for example:

```
    override fun callUser(onSuccess:Runnable, onFailure:Runnable){

 NetworkManager.instance.performCall(NetworkManager.REGISTRATION.verifyUser(id),
                object : NetworkManager.OnRequestCallback<UserInfoResponse> {
                    override fun onSuccess(body: UserInfoResponse?) {
                        body?.data?.let {
                            onSuccess.run()
                        }
                    }

                    override fun onError(errorBody: String?) {
                        onFailure.run()
                    }
                })
    }
```

Then I go to a fragment and call the method above like this:

```
objectManager.callVerifyAdvisor(
                    Runnable {[On Success stuff },
                    Runnable {[On Error]}
        }
```

The problem is that, although I can decide in the fragment the actions I want to do in the `onSuccess()` and `onFailure()` methods, I cant get the `API Results` to that fragment by doing this way.

So my ideia is to do something like [**I used comments to specify the sections that matter**]:

```
NetworkManager.instance.performCall(NetworkManager.REGISTRATION.verifyUser(id),
                    object : NetworkManager.OnRequestCallback<UserInfoResponse> {
                        override fun onSuccess(body: UserInfoResponse?) {
                            body?.data?.let {
                                it.userName // I get this from api response
                                onSuccess.run()
                            }
                        }

                        override fun onError(errorBody: String?) {
                            onFailure.run()
                        }
                    })
        }
```

Then on my **fragment** I want something like this:

```
   objectManager.callVerifyAdvisor(
              Runnable {[On Success stuff }, //receive here the it.userName
              Runnable {[On Error]}
}
```

Can someone give any ideia how to do this? Side note -> I put kotlin on the tag because this has some kind of functional stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to replace you onSuccess from `Runnable` to your custom functional type callback:

```
override fun callUser(onSuccess: (String) -> Unit, onFailure: Runnable) {...
```

Then pass userName to callback:

```
NetworkManager.instance.performCall(NetworkManager.REGISTRATION.verifyUser(id),
                object : NetworkManager.OnRequestCallback<UserInfoResponse> {
                    override fun onSuccess(body: UserInfoResponse?) {
                        body?.data?.let {
                            onSuccess.invoke(it.userName) // Pass userName
                        }
                    }

                    override fun onError(errorBody: String?) {
                        onFailure.run()
                    }
                })
    }
```

And then you can get userName from this callback:

```
objectManager.callVerifyAdvisor(
          {userName -> } // Here you get your result
          Runnable {[On Error]}
}
```